# How to limit the number of columns in a MySQL table when units can have multiple values for a field?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Suppose the unit of analysis is a person. I want to have one column for the name and another column for the language he or she speaks. Some people speak many languages whereas some only speak one. However, I don't want to my table to look like name, language1, language2, language3, language4, language5 because that will produce a lot of empty cells. Ideally I would only have 2 columns but I know it is impossible to shove multiple values into a single cell. Any ideas?

Comment: You would need 2 tables, one `users` with `user_id` and `name`, a related one `user_languages` with `user_id` and `language` so user with multiple languages would have multiple rows in the `user_languages` table.

Comment: To take @AbraCadaver's comment one step further; I'd suggest three tables: `users`, `languages`, and `user_languages`. In this case `user_languages` would have `user_id` and `language_id` fields; this design establishes a list of languages (and canonical language "name" spellings), and prevents different users from having "English", "english", "eng", etc...

Answer (score 0):

You have a **many-to-many** relationship, so what you're looking for is known as a [**bridging table** (or associative entity)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity).

What you want is one table called `people` that represents the individuals, and another table called `languages` for each language. Each person and each language constitute a separate row in their respective tables.

`people`:

```
ID | Name
----------
1  | Aaron
2  | Bob
3  | Clyde
```

`languages`:

```
ID | Name
------------
1  | English
2  | French
3  | Spanish
```

Then you need to make use of a **third** table (say `spoken_languages`), which makes use of foreign keys to tie the two tables together:

```
person_id | language_id
-----------------------
1         | 1
2         | 1
2         | 2
3         | 3
```

In the above example:

- Aaron only speaks English.
- Bob speaks both English and French.
- Clyde only speaks Spanish.